# When are two quantum descriptions / models equivalent?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, constrained-dynamics, quantization

I am occupied with different types of quantization methods for constrained systems. I start with a constrained phase space and then follow two different paths to get rid of the constraints. In the end, after many complicated manipulations, both paths should lead to the same description of the quantum system. For now, I only proved that the final Hamiltonians are equal.

Is this proof enough that the two descriptions are equal? Or do I need other "ingredients" besides the Hamiltonian to fully characterize a description (such as the underlying Hilbert space, the bracket structure, etc.)? In general, how do I prove that two quantum descriptions are fully equivalent?